# How do I optimize my ul navigation for mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using [Gridset](https://gridsetapp.com/) to create a dynamic website. So far, things are going great. When I hit my breakpoint, it gracefully transitions to its mobile counterpart. However, I noticed that when I tested this on my phone, the site was way larger then the viewing area of my phone, even though it was using the correct mobile grid.

Here are two screen shots of the layouts in both forms, viewed from my desktop

[Desktop](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipDesktop.jpg)

[Mobile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipMobile.jpg)

However, when I view on my phone, you have to scroll horizontally to view the whole thing. I tried to fix this by using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This did what I wanted it too. And I thought I fixed my issue. Until I viewed it on my phone in horizontal mode. It cuts off the last navigation option 'contact'

Here is a screenshot from my phone

[phone Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/Screenshot_2014-03-14-10-10-34.png)

It looks fine on any tablet in any orientation. Phones work when in landscape mode.

So what my question ultimately is, how can I prevent my ul navigation from being cut off when viewed on phones in horizontal mode.

Here is a link to the website if you want to view the source

[link](http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/index.html)

Edit*

Because i want to center the log in and inquire icons I had to remove the float. This prevents them from being on the same line though.

```
/*center icons on mobile*/
@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 989px){
    #headerIcons img{
        display:block;
        float:none;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;

    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or is there a different way to make sure the images stay on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height: 60px` from `#navigation` ...

... and it's fixed. The LI elements inside are floating, so they drop down to another row when there's not enough width to display all on one. The problem was the fixed height: the container (#navigation) was unable to expand to contain them when they drop down.

**EDIT**

If you want the nav items to all fit on one line, you'll need to use media queries to adjust the layout. For example, add this to your stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { /* increase this width until you see the desired results */
    #navigationPages li {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    #navigationPages li a {
        padding: 0.75em 0.6em;
    }
}
```

This media query reduces the font size and link padding for windows that are 320px wide or less. You can adjust that width as needed. If you are new to media queries, it would be a good idea to google about them. They are instrumental in mobile responsive website development.

Comment: This is a great start! However, because my navigation is too large it is wrapping contact to the next line.

 [example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/Screenshot_2.png)

Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: This is a great solution and works when I resize my browser below 320px. However, when i view on my phone, it doesnt resize. Is this maybe because my phone is more than 320 pixels?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to increase that number to the width of your phone. Or better yet, the width needed  to display correctly at any width. Looks like 468px is the value you'll want.

Comment: This worked. You have been immensely helpful. Would you please explain to me how you came up with that value?

Comment: No worries! Sure, it was by resizing the browser window on your demo until the point where the navigation was too big to fit on one row (468px wide). Then you know a change needs to be made at that point. Using Google Chrome developer tools, it tells you the current window dimensions as you resize.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would like to ask you one more question if i could. I am trying to get the log in and inquire images to center when on mobile.
 In the edit i will show the code i tried. It worked, but it caused the images to not float next to each other. Is there a way I can prevent them from breaking to the next line without using float?

Comment: Really you should ask that as a new question as it's a different problem. Feel free to post a link to your new question here and I'll take a look.